# Move this "Submit: Button

Tags: css, genesis

My website is http://boasish.com

I would like to know how I can move my "Submit" Button up like it is on this site http://www.theminimalists.com

Facebook

            Twitter

            Pinterest

            RSS

Comment: Print a screencapture of your site onto paper, get some scissors, cut out the submit button, and glue it in the new location.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of the page and figure it out?

Comment: Your question is **not likely to help anyone in the future**. While asking questions you need to post the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue. If you never seen anyone ask questions on this site, or you just don't know http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read the [help]

Comment: I have been looking at the source of the page for about 2 days and haven't been able to figure out what to change in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change padding for to what you see below

```
.feature-area .feature-area-bottom {    
    padding: 0 0 9px;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. I've been trying to change it for 2 days. Now I know.

Comment: use firebug for debugging the code!

Answer (score 0):

Without any code in your question, this is a general answer.

You can change the `position:` attribute in `css` to either `absolute` or `relative`, and then use positioning commands such as `top` and `left` to relocate it.

Note that `absolute` elements are positioned in relation to their nearest `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` div.

```
$('#sub1').css({'position':'absolute','top':'20px','left':'150px'});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6qqLv/)

References:

[Is it possible to use position relative more than once in the same html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463799/is-it-possible-to-use-position-relative-more-than-once-in-the-same-html-page/25463862#25463862)